# VSE snap a strip to the begining of your editing

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In the VSE is there a way to snap strips to the begining of your editing? For example you've deleted the first strip of you editing, your editing now starts at frame 200 and you want to move all of your strips to frame 0 or frame 1, is there a simple way to do that snapping to the begining of the VSE?

Comment: Surely you can just select all the strips, move the scrubber to where you want to snap, and hit Shift+S?

Comment: That will only work for one strip with the desired result...

Answer (score 5):

Group all of your strips (**Make** them a **Meta Strip** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and then with your current Frame being 1 (position the green playhead) press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to **Snap** the Meta **s** to the beginning. *Alternatively set the Meta Strips Start Frame to 1.* Then **UnMeta**/ungroup the **Strip** again: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I would select all clips and press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>200</kbd> (if your edit starts at frame 200). This will move all clips 200 frames to the beginning of the timeline.

If you have Sync Markers enabled (*View* > *Sync Markers*), the selected markers will move with the clips.
To select all markers press <kbd>A</kbd> with your mouse over the timeline.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47750/2843

Answer (score 0):

The [Extra Sequencer Action](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Sequencer/Extra_Sequencer_Actions) Add-on has a *Ripple Delete* feature. With that you can just create a Dummy Strip (like a Color *Effect Strip*) from Frame 1 to the Frame before the rest of your footage that you want to move. And then perform this Ripple Delete on that Dummy Strip which should move the rest of your strips afterwards to the left including the Keyframes, etc...